# function in my code not working

Tags: python, index-error

I'm making a program which include some validation

```
number = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

def UsernameValidation():
    New_Username_char = ("")
    Valid = 0
    if not len(New_Username) <= 4:
        print("Username too short")
    for i in range(0, len(New_Username) - 2):
        New_Username_char[i] = str(New_Username[i])
    if New_Username_char.islower():
        print("Username should be in uppercase")
        Valid += 1
    if New_Username[len(New_Username)] not in number or New_Username[len(New_Username)-1] not in number:
        print("The Username should be followed by two number")
        Valid += 1
```

and these errors come up

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\FIle Handling\Mini Project.py", line 71, in     
>     CreateAccount()
>   File "C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\FIle Handling\Mini Project.py", line 60, in   CreateAccount
>     GetUsername()
>   File "C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\FIle Handling\Mini Project.py", line 41, in   GetUsername
>     UsernameValidation()
>   File "C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\FIle Handling\Mini Project.py", line 33, in   UsernameValidation
>     if New_Username[len(New_Username)] not in number or   New_Username[len(New_Username)-1] not in number:
>   IndexError: string index out of range

when I print out the length of the `New_Username` it shows up `0` (there should be something in New_Username)

Comment: Well `New_Username[len(New_Username)]`, `len(x)` is not valid for a list/string `x` since the indices range from `0` to `len(x)-1` (both inclusive).

Comment: The highest index in a string, list, etc, is one less than its length, so `New_Username[len(New_Username)]` is trying to index beyond the end of the string.

Comment: also what is `number`?

Comment: BTW, the `UsernameValidation` function should accept the username it's validating as an argument. It shouldn't read it from the global context, that's just messy.

Comment: Surely `if not len(New_Username) <= 4:` should be `if len(New_Username) <= 4`

Comment: `New_Username_char[i]` seems to think that `New_Username_char` isn't an empty string. This should fail. I don't think you're showing us the real code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated version of your function. There were a couple of things wrong with it as you can see in the comments below.

```
def UsernameValidation(new_username):
    new_username = str(new_username)
    if len(new_username) <= 4:
        print("Username too short")
        return False
    if any(x.islower() for x in new_username):
        print("Username should be in uppercase")
        return False
    if not new_username[-2:].isnumeric():
        print("The Username should be followed by two numbers")
        return False
    print('Password accepted!')
    return True

print(UsernameValidation('and'))       # too short          - REJECTED
print(UsernameValidation('ANDrEW'))    # contains lowercase - REJECTED
print(UsernameValidation('ANDREW'))    # no numbers         - REJECTED
print(UsernameValidation('ANDREW12'))  #          ACCEPTED
```

Suggestions:

- Spent some time reading about indexes
- Use lowercase letters for variables
- you do not have to use loops for everything. There are functions that do that for you (`str()`, `any()` in this example)
- Functions should return something. A function called `UsernameValidation` would be expected to return a boolean based on is name
- do not use the global namespace in a function if you do not have to. Pass arguments instead.
- Do not declare variables if you do not need them (`number = [...]`)

Comment: Please add comments to explain why those changes where necessary.

Answer (score -1):

`New_Username[len(New_Username) - 1]` is the last character in New_Username, you try to access one character beyond that by saying `New_Username[len(New_Username)]`

The index of the first character in a string is 0, the next 1, then 2, then 3 and so on, example:

```
String: 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'
Index:   0 ,  1 ,  2 ,  3 ,  4
```

`len(string)` returns the amount of characters in a string, in the following example the amount of characters is 5, and 5 is out of bounds, example:

```
String: 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'
Index:   0 ,  1 ,  2 ,  3 ,  4 ,  5
                                  ^
    There is no character at index 5, so an IndexError is thrown
```